# how do I send json response from non activity class to activity class in android

Tags: android

In my application I need to send the `json` response of non activity class to activity  class.i am getting null in both non activity class and activity class. I am new to java and android. please help me out.

payment.java:

```
 public String getJson() {
                     payjson=OrderItem.toString();

                    Log.v("In payment class",payjson);


                return payjson;
            }
```

PaymentActivtyclass:

```
pay = new Payment(getApplicationContext());
                        json=pay.getJson();
                        Log.v("In Activity Class",""+json);
```

Here payment class  is the non activity class and payment activity class is the activity class

Comment: Check your `OrderItem`. It may be null.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do so..
First way: you need to use setter getter. Refer this given link [Click here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-generate-getters-and-setters.html)

Second way: you need to use sharedprefs to solve this problem. Here's the link [Click here](http://www.androidaspect.com/2013/09/android-shared-preferences-tutorial.html)